# splitting a string into N number of strings

Tags: java, string, split, char

I want to split a string into N number of 2char strings. I know I must use String.subSequence. However I want it to keep creating these until the string is > 2

Comment: what happened?
Someone just posted the extact answer to my problem using a vector which is now gone :S Can someone explain this?

Comment: probably the poster deleted the answer, I read it and it didn't compile

Comment: @Will, that person removed his/her answer (probably because it was wrong).

Comment: He had some sytanx errors which I amended. But the logic seemed sound

Comment: @Will, no it was wrong: inside the answer something like this happened: `... = s.substring(2, s.length() - 1)` (the `2` is incorrect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int n = 3;
String s = "abcdefghijkl";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString( s.split("(?<=\\G.{2})(?=.)", n + 1 ) ) );

//prints: [ab, cd, ef, ghijkl], i.e. you have 3 2-char groups and the rest
```

The regex works as follows: find any position after 2 characters (zero-width postive look behind `(?<=...)`) starting from the last match position (`\G`) and before at least one more character (zero-width positive look ahead `(?=.)`). This should not match the positions at the start and end of the string and thus n can be as big as you want without resulting in an empty string at the start or the end.

Edit: if you want to split as much as possible, just leave out the second parameter to split.

Example:

```
String digits = "123456789";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString( digits.split("(?<=\\G.{2})(?=.)" ) ) ); //no second parameter

//prints: [12, 34, 56, 78, 9]
```

Comment: nice suggestion but I think he needs this example with    n = s.length()/2

Comment: @ashiaka If there's no constraint, then the second parameter to  `split()` should be left out. That way the split is performed as often as possible. I'll add an example.

Comment: Very nice piece of code. Makes me want to brush up my regex :)
Cheers Thomas

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "asdasdasd";
List<String> segments = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i=i+2) {
    segments.add(s.substring(i-1, i+1));
}
System.out.println(segments.toString());
```